# running yarn fails to build after updating node version

Tags: node.js, package.json, node-sass

I've updated my node version from 14 to 18 and now I'm seeing build errors around node_sass.
I've updated node_sass to v8 in my package.json file, removed the node_modules folder and yarn.lock file then ran yarn again but the issue keeps appearing.

Heres the error:

```
node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
```

I'm guessing the node_sass version needs updating for rails too but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `node-sass`, use `sass`.

Comment: @AKX I've seen this a few times when searching for an answer, why? Is node-sass no longer needed or is this just the new convention?

Comment: `node-sass` uses a native binary module that's not easy to compile (which is what you're seeing); `sass` is pure JavaScript and fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you AKX for the help, I've ended up sticking with node-sass for now as this is a huge project but we're going to discuss moving to sass now.

My specific issue was fixed by updating `@rails/webpacker`

now yarn works as expected.